# How to remember various set operations very easily?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, advice

I need an way to remember the set operations very easily.

Does anybody have any idea?

For example, how do you remember the distinction between Set-Intersection and Set-difference? I regularly mess it up.

Comment: Do as many questions in your book as you have time for.

Comment: Union is marked by a symbol resembling a u, and union starts with u, so that one's easy. Then intersection is the opposite of a union (sort of), and the symbol is the upside down union, so that's not too hard. Which other operations do you want?

Comment: How do you remember the difference between **V** and **U**? They are so similar! Or between **p,q,b,d**? Or whatever letters which are similar in your native language.

Answer (score 3):

As 5xum mentioned in the comments, union starts with a u and has a symbol $\cup$ that looks very much like a $u$. Then intersection is simply the same symbol flipped $\cap$.

As for what they mean, you can think of union $A \cup B$ as a cup (indeed, the LaTeX command for it is `\cup`) in which you pour *all* of the elements of both $A$ and $B$, whereas $A \cap B$ has two legs, one in $A$ and one in $B$, so it contains only those elements that are in both $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 0):

The trick I used to memorize them actually stemmed from formal logic (which you may or may not have had any exposure to):

The symbol $\land$ is a way to symbolize the binary connective "and". Notice it looks like a "pointy" $\cap$. Similarly $\lor$ (or) looks similar to $\cup$.

Now,
$$x\in A\cap B$$
can be read as
$$x\text{ is in } A \textbf{ and } B$$
and
$$x\in A\cup B$$
is
$$x\text{ is in } A \textbf{ or } B$$

This might actually be why the symbols look similar, actually.